# No WPF messages in the Visual Studio Output Window!

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I debug a solution that contains a WPF module.

I use the OutputWindow to trace some variable values.

However, once I open the WPF component I recieve in the output Window a lot of "Errors" like

"...Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property...." etc.

How to avoid that messages?

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

Installed Version: Ultimate

I should **uncheck** the "Program Output" (???) in order to see just the "Program output"...

never know...

Answer (score 4):

Those messages indicate errors in your data binding. You should check your data bindings defined in WPF.

Comment: WPF is not my module. I don't care about WPF. I want not not see error messages in the output window. That is all. I intentionally indicated that the error messages are *deactivated*, but apparently I didn't unckeck the right option...

Comment: the reason is that the question was't about how to *solve* the error(s), but about how to *hide* the error messages without the need to solve the errors.

Comment: @serhio Thanks for the clarification. I obviously misunderstood the word _avoid_. Please make sure to be more specific with your next question, because here are, like me, a lot non-native speakers around.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Option and then

Debugging -> Output Window

under WPF Trace Settings, increase Data Binding level Error/Critical

or have a look at other settings in there

as PVitt mentioned, it is an error with your Binding, seems to be your XAML code is trying to do binding for some properties and it is failing

Comment: I set it to Off. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your application entry point.  For example, in MainWindow constructor.

System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;

Example:

```
MainWindow()
{
    System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```